# Using Spring/Strut AND AutoLayout (Xcode 8)

Tags: xcode, ios-autolayout

All the topics i saw here was one vs another.

My question is:

It is possible to use Autolayout AND spring and struts effectively? If you don't set any constrains to the object you'll see that you still have the old spring and strut interface on the Size Inspector tab.

The problem is, im doing a test App for iPhone only and to be honest spring and struts works like a charm for 90% of the cases (even if the width/height ratio is different like iPhone 4).

But for the 10% constrains is needed to get the results i want. (Table Views, dynamic text and so on).

I couldn't find anything to see if Apple is still maintaining struts and springs (they must have since you can still use them) but i know Auto Layout is a improved version of spring and struts and Apple focus is Auto Layout.

Of course a 100% Auto Layout approach would be the best option but for setting simple things like a button i don't know why isn't spring / strut a viable solution. (Considering you are not doing a iPhone and iPad app)

So, it is possible to use both or i'll have problems in the future? (Considering im doing an App JUST for iPhone or iPad, never both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible to use Autolayout AND spring and struts effectively

Yes, absolutely. This has always been true if your views are created in code. But starting in Xcode 8 you can also do it in Interface Builder, i.e. you can combine the two in the same nib (xib/storyboard).

Comment: Yes im using both in the same nib actually and im glad it seems to work. I was afraid that Auto Layout couldn't "read" very well the Auto resize and would bug my entire nib. I didn't knew you could use both in code (its rare that i create a nib in code). Thanks a lot matt, im more relived now to know that this will work (at least for now).

Comment: But if you could answer one more thing, it is rare to use both auto layout and spring struts? Everything i could find is using one or another, never both. I don't know how good people find using both.

Comment: You don't find examples of it because of what I said in my answer: before Xcode 8 it wasn't possible. If the nib (storyboard) said "Use Auto Layout", all views in it used autolayout — the springs and struts interface never appeared.

Comment: But it was by code, right? I did some research if people did this with code but i didn't find anything. Anyway i maybe find more things in the future since its possible now in xcode8. Thanks again matt!